# Google Keep notifications are delayed on Samsung Note 4

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-note-4, google-keep

The reminders set in Google Keep are not displayed in time. It happens after the time has passed. I have power saver on and with limited background apps. Is it the reason?

Comment: Could be. If you're on Marshmallow, then doze could be one of the reasons why you have delayed notifications. I'm not sure what power saver does in Samsung, but I'm willing to bet it kills background data activity and alarms of lesser priority. Why don't you test to check whether this is happening when the battery saver mode is off

Comment: But some times it shows correctly even with power saver on.

Comment: is it just google keep or are you having the same trouble with other apps that show notifications and alarms as well?

Comment: I don't have any other apps that shows notifications when on background mode. All alarms happens correctly. No issues with alarm.